# Are power-up purchases permanent?

Tags: retro-city-rampage

In *Retro City Rampage* are the powerups I purchase from the power up shop permanent? I know the ones I get as part of missions will expire, I'd rather not spend most of my money on them if that is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After building up some money, it seems that power ups are like any other weapon. They are permanent except that you will lose them if you die outside of a mission.

Power-ups also function as additional health, any damage you take will be first applied to the power-up's Ⓟ meter. So if say a police car or two plow into you while on a constitutional with your rocket launcher, you will lose the power-up first, then start taking damage when it is gone.

There seems to be no way to restore lost Ⓟ meter (other than buy a new power up).

Saving and reloading will reset the meter.